# ECS Nginx network setup

Tags: nginx, amazon-ecs

I have 3 containers on ECS: web, api and nginx. Basically nginx is proxying traffic to `web` and `api` containers:

```
upstream web {
  server web-container:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api-container:3001;
}
```

But every time I redeploy `web` or `api` they change their IPs so I need to redeploy `nginx` afterwards in order to make it to "pick up" new IPs.

Is there a way to avoid this so I could just update let's say `api` service and `nginx` service would automatically proxy to correct IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume these containers belong to 3 different task definitions and ultimately 3 different tasks (or better 3 different services).

If that is the setup then you want to use [service discovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html) for this. This only works with ECS services and the idea is that you create 3 distinct services each with 1+ tasks in it. You give the service a name (e.g. `nginx`, `web`, `api`) and each container in them is going to be able to resolve the other containers by pointing to the fqdn (e.g. `api.local`). When your container in the nginx service tries to connect to `api.local` service discovery will resolve that name to the IP of one of the tasks in the ECS service `api`.

If you want to see an example re how this is setup you can look at this [demo app](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/tree/master/deployments/platformdeployment/AWS/ECS) and particularly at [this CloudFormation template](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/deployments/platformdeployment/AWS/ECS/cfn/yelb-cloudformation-ECS-deployment.yaml)